# PHP: custom session handler

Tags: php, session, handler

just a small question regarding the php session handler,
let's say i want to store the session in a database because i have multiple servers that should have access to the session, i would write my own sessionhandler using the interface as described in http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php,
but how can i use it? 
if i do

```
session_set_save_handler(....);
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = 'value';
```

will it save the data using my handler?

Comment: Yes, it will, as long as you wrote it right.

Comment: OP, this is getting down-votes because you don't include relevant code and ask for a code review (on non-existent code, mind you). Code reviews can be posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that you define and set in set_save_handler() should have all the functions required in the lifetime of a session to be defined. These include read(), write(), destroy() among others.

Once that is defined correctly you can still manipulate sessions the normal way you do, but in the background, the functions you define will get executed based on which session event you are performing.

For e.g. $_SESSION['key'] = 'value' will perform the write() function (in which you might have coded a database save routine)

You can read more about it at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php